# I want a desktop icon on the left of taskbar to look like the word icon

Tags: desktop, desktop-icons

Is it true I can not place a shortcut for my "desktop" to the left of the taskbar?  I want it to look just like the Word, folders Excel One Note icons.  It seems like it should be a simple thing.

I just did not want to give up, but my IT guy says it's not possible, as it is already to the far right.  Also, when I click on the `Start` button, there is not a button for desktop... is this normal?

Comment: Why? If you want to go to the desktop, on Win7, just click the small rectangle to the right of the time and date

Comment: "wow it just seems like a simple thing" so simple they already included it...

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know why you want to do this, this is how:

1. Go to the desktop, right click, `New` > `Shortcut`.
2. Type `%windir%\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}` (from [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/26379-show-desktop-shortcut-create.html))
3. Click `Next`. Name the shortcut as `Microsoft Word` (or whatever you want)
4. Click `Finish`. Right click the new icon, click `Change Icon`, go to the Microsoft Word directory (or whichever program icon you want), find the icon, double click it, click `OK`.
5. Right click the icon again, `Pin to Taskbar`. Move the icon to the left, as you want.

Done.